# How do I set variables equal for the first period and allow them to differ for all remaining periods in GAMS?

Tags: variables, definition, gams-math

I´m running the DICE2013 model and want to state a condition that two variables should be equal in the first period t, before they can be optimized independently for all remaining periods.

Do I write an if statement at the beginning or how can I best achieve this?

AI(t)=BI(t) if t=1, thereafter the two should be unrelated

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new equation to your model, such as:

```
EQUATION NewEquation;
NewEquation..  AI(1) =e= BI(1);
```

In this way, you are adding a constraint only for t = 1.
I hope it helps

Comment: We need quotes:  `AI('1') =e= BI('1');`